# non-linear differential equation bernoulli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In performing Bernoulli diff equation integration, the prof assumes the following:

$e^{-x}$du/dx - $e^{-x}$u $\implies$ d/dx(u$e^{-x}$)

However isn't the derivative of d/dx(u$e^{-x}$) = -(u$e^{-x}$), since we are keeping u constant in the d/dx and not differentiating with respect to u?

Comment: Not when $u$ is not constant, but rather some function of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not performing a partial derivation.   When $u$ is a function of $x$, then you use the Product Rule (and since $\tfrac{\mathrm d~~~}{\mathrm d~x}e^{-x}=-e^{-x}$), to obtain:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d~ue^{-x}}{\mathrm d~x~~~~~~}=-ue^{-x}+e^{-x}\dfrac{\mathrm d~u}{\mathrm d~x}$$

Comment: yes thank you i mistook this for a partial derivative instead of treating u as a function and differentiating it wrt to x